# Suspicious upvotes

Tags: discussion, up-votes

Quoting from a [posting on Arduino Meta](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2669/suspicious-upvotes): "User dannyf gets every day since October upvotes on three to five old answers. That makes around 2400 points in two months."

Looking at [this bit of their profile](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/136014/dannyf?tab=answers), I wouldn't be surprised the same is going on on EE.

It's just a heads-up, but as I am supposed to ask a question: Should somebody look into this?

Comment: I couldn't see anything, their last post was in '17.  And their rep has only been going up 10 per every 3 or 4 days, and has even gone down at some points because of their poor quality answers (as anyone with over 20000 rep can see I think). Contact the arduino mods and they will check for problems.

Comment: The Arduino mods have already concluded there was a problem and have removed the offending upvotes on SE Arduino; I just wondered if somebody was pulling the same stunt here on EE.

Comment: If they had sock accounts, they will be removed and any votes will go with them on both sites